# Laravel 5.4 update all records in table without using where clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to update all records from table withing single eloquent query in Laravel 5.4

```
Currency::update(['default'=>0]);
```

I am expecting that this query will update all the records from a table, but this query isn't working. It is expecting where clause and I don't want to put any conditions using where clause, I just want to update all records in a table.

I am not getting any answer from laravel documentation.

Table Structure
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL has a safe update server mode which will not allow an update to happen unless the statement has a `WHERE` clause involving the primary key.  If your MySQL be running in this mode, then one way to spoof it would be to use `WHERE id = id`, something like this:

```
DB::table('Currency')
        ->where('id', 'id')
        ->update(['default' => 0]);
```

Comment: I got this, so it is mandatory to put where clause in query or else query won't work at all, thanks

Comment: @dollar You could also disable safe updates in MySQL using a number of methods.  The mode is there to help you avoid doing an accidental blanket update which wipes out a table.  If you are a judicious MySQL user, then maybe you can turn off safe mode.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, I would stick with your suggested solution instead of turning off safe mode in MySQL.

Comment: This did not work for me in Laravel 5.1, it did not throw any errors but updated 0 rows. To fix it I had to remove the`->where('id', 'id')` line and add: `DB::statement("SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;");` before my query and `DB::statement("SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;");` afterwards so it goes back to the safe mode.

Comment: @VinGarcia This may have more to do with the underlying version of Laravel which you are using.  AFAIK Laravel just wraps MySQL under the hood.

Comment: You can use Model::whereRaw(1) to insert a dummy WHERE clause which always evaluates to true. Less processing time required than using other dummy conditions.

Answer (score 4):

`Product::query()->update(['default' => 0, ]);`

Simple query to update all rows of the table.

Comment: Hello Aftab, welcome to SO , a short explanation can be comment , if it is a longer description then you can put it as answer

Comment: It's more appropriate to have this as a separate answer.

Answer (score 3):

If your MySQL server running SQL_SAFE_UPDATES mode you can use "where" like this. Or another "where clause" that includes all results.

```
Currency::where('id', '>', 0)->update(['default' => 0]);
```